# How can I display the image as a thumbnail

Tags: c++, image, qt, thumbnails, qt5

I have a `QTreeView` to display the hard drives and Directories. also I have a `QListView` to display the images files as the following:

[image]

But I want to display the images as thumbnails, like the following:

[image]

**My code:**

```
mainWidget::mainWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::mainWidget){
    ui->setupUi(this);
    dirsModel = new QFileSystemModel;
    filesModel = new QFileSystemModel;
    dirsModel->setRootPath("");
    ui->treeView->setModel(dirsModel);
    ui->listView->setModel(filesModel);
    dirsModel->setFilter(QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
    filesModel->setFilter(QDir::Files);
    ui->treeView->hideColumn(1);
    ui->treeView->hideColumn(2);
    ui->treeView->hideColumn(3);
    ui->treeView->header()->hide();
}

void mainWidget::on_treeView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index){
    ui->listView->setRootIndex(filesModel->setRootPath(dirsModel->filePath(index)));
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know what is the way of changing the image view from icon to thumbnail.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what you are after there are better ways to go about it I think, but here is an example based on a project of mine in python:

What you can do is subclass the QFileIconProvider:

```
ICON_SIZE = QSize(64,64)
accepted_types = (".jpg",".tiff",".png",".exr",".psd")

# this depends on the plugins you have installed,
# PSD and EXR requires external ones).

class IconProvider(QFileIconProvider):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def icon(self, type: 'QFileIconProvider.IconType'):

        fn = type.filePath()

        if fn.endswith(accepted_types):
            a = QPixmap(ICON_SIZE)
            a.load(fn)
            return QIcon(a)
        else:
            return super().icon(type)
```

Then on the Model you use:

```
self.fileSystemModel.setIconProvider(IconProvider)
```

Example on TreeView:
[image: Custom Icon Provider Preview]

Answer (score 4):

You should use special `ViewMode`:

```
 ui->listView->setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
```

But it will show you only icons(not whole images), so I think you should create for example `QStandardItemModel` (because `QFileSystemModel` is not very suitable)  and set pixmap to this model with `Qt::DecorationRole`, but scale this images to smaller size. As you understand if there are many images in the dir, this process can be long.

As you can see, you should every time (every `on_treeView_clicked`) get new list of images in the directory, You can do this with:

```
QStringList QDir::entryList(const QStringList & nameFilters, Filters filters = NoFilter, SortFlags sort = NoSort) const
```

with special filters. When you have list of files, in the loop you can create pixmaps, scale it and set to model.

By default `QListView::IconMode` provide Free movement. If you want avoid this you should use:

```
ui->listView->setMovement(QListView::Static);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was hope to see more detail, because the subject still unclear.

Comment: What is your opinion for this way which in this [[link](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/27412)] ?

Comment: @LionKing in your code you work with view and models so my solution is for view too. Anyways in this link people recommend to use listview and icon mode too.

Comment: I don't care work by using models or not, I want the way to do this work only.

Comment: @LionKing my opinion is the listView better, you should not create layout, hundreds of qlabel and scrollarea, you have listView with icon mode and just set new images to your model and delete old data. Anyways you can't avoid loading images from directory. In my answer there are all needed. AFAIK this task can't be done with one special Qt method.