# How to get the files that not appear in the QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm use `QTreeView` with  `setFilter()` function to allow to display the directories and drivers only but files does not allowed.

But I want to get the files that don't appear in `QTreeView`, with continue display the directories and drivers only without files in `QTreeView`.

```
QFileSystemModel dirsModel = new QFileSystemModel;
dirsModel->setRootPath("");
ui->treeView->setModel(dirsModel);
dirsModel->setFilter(QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
```

**How can I do that ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said earlier you need to get `entryList`. For example:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QModelIndex ind = ui->treeView->currentIndex();
    QFileSystemModel *sys = qobject_cast<QFileSystemModel*>( ui->treeView->model());
    QString path = sys->filePath(ind);
    qDebug() << path;
    QDir dir(path);
    QStringList files = dir.entryList(QStringList(), QDir::Files);
    if(!files.size())
         qDebug()<< "Empty";
    else
        for(int i=0 ; i<files.size();i++)
            qDebug() << files.at(i);
}
```

We used `QFileSystemModel` here only to get current path, `entryList` is absolutely separate from this.

Comment: When you said earlier, your words were not clear. but now with that example I'm understood. also I have an inquiry (what is the benefit of `QStringList()` here `dir.entryList(QStringList(), .. )`?

Comment: @LionKing Earlier because of this your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703774/how-can-i-display-the-image-as-a-thumbnail/26703830#26703830 empty stringlist means no filters, we can get all files or just jpg wav etc, we want all files so list is empty, second argument means that we don't need get dirs inside this dir, only files.

Comment: When I want to get the png files only, is this correct, `dir.entryList(QStringList() << ".*png", QDir::Files);`

Comment: @LionKing *.png should be

Comment: Thanks, and `+1` for you.